# Implement Generic Interface via CodeDom

Tags: vb.net, generics, codedom

The CodeDom is not generating legal VB for me when I try to implement a generic interface.

Here is my VB code to generate the VB code.

```
Private Sub RunTest()

    Dim compileUnit = New CodeCompileUnit

    Dim ns As New CodeNamespace()
    compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(ns)
    ns.Imports.Add(New CodeNamespaceImport("System"))
    ns.Imports.Add(New CodeNamespaceImport("System.Collections.Generic"))

    Dim fooCollection = New CodeTypeDeclaration("FooCollection")
    ns.Types.Add(fooCollection)
    fooCollection.TypeAttributes = Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public
    fooCollection.IsClass = True
    fooCollection.BaseTypes.Add(New CodeTypeReference(GetType(System.Object)))
    fooCollection.BaseTypes.Add(New CodeTypeReference( _
        "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" _
        , New CodeTypeReference() {New CodeTypeReference("Foo")} _
    ))

    Dim method = New CodeMemberMethod
    fooCollection.Members.Add(method)
    method.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private
    method.Name = "GetEnumerator"
    method.ReturnType = New CodeTypeReference( _
        "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" _
        , New CodeTypeReference() {New CodeTypeReference("Foo")} _
    )
    method.PrivateImplementationType = New CodeTypeReference( _
        "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" _
        , New CodeTypeReference() {New CodeTypeReference("Foo")} _
    )

    Dim provider = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
    Dim options = New Compiler.CodeGeneratorOptions
    Dim writer = New IO.StringWriter
    provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileUnit, writer, options)
    Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString)

End Sub
```

And that will generate:

```
Public Class FooCollection
    Inherits Object
    Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Foo)

    Function System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable`1_GetEnumerator() _
    As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Foo) _
    Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Foo).GetEnumerator

    End Function

End Class
```

The problem is the name of the function.  The tick mark in the function name doesn't make for a legal function name.

It seems that when using the PrivateImplentationType property of the CodeMethodMethod the Name property gets used as the name of the method you are implementing, not the name of the function.

How do you explicitly set the function name or at least how do I get it to be something legal?

Comment: The order of the assignment to the Name property has no affect.

Comment: Summarising my previous (now deleted) comments: The order of setting the `.Name` is not important; the private `GetBaseTypeOutput` is unconditionally prepended to `Name`, but it includes logic checking for ``"`"c`` in .NET Framework 4, however that still produces bad code referring to `System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable(Of Foo)_GetEnumerator`!

Comment: It doesn't help solve the problem, but your return type should be `"System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a compilable output, just use `ImplementationTypes`: I just changed one line of your code (but I include a simple line for reference, and the corrected `ReturnType`):

```
method.Name = "GetEnumerator"
method.ReturnType = New CodeTypeReference( _
    "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator" _
    , New CodeTypeReference() {New CodeTypeReference("Foo")} _
)
method.ImplementationTypes.Add(New CodeTypeReference( _
    "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" _
    , New CodeTypeReference() {New CodeTypeReference("Foo")} _
))
```

<sub>There doesn't seem to be a simple workaround using `PrivateImplementationType`. Microsoft's code in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeGenerator.GenerateMethod` (which is in a `Friend` class so not easily overridden) caters for `.`'s, replacing them with `_`, but forgets to cater for `` ` `` in .NET 2.0-3.5 and `(Of <type>)` in 4.0. It is probably worth logging a bug at Connect, including pointing out the method name should be separately overridable compared to the method name on the interface being implemented.</sub>

You seem to need the functionality of `PrivateImplementationType` to support the non-generic `GetEnumerator`. [Here](http://pastebin.com/9V1RyDdp) is my simple adjustment of your original code to produce a single compilable library, with only warnings about empty code. This code still has "issues", such as the `method.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private` being ignored where `PrivateImplementationType` is used...

Comment: Thanks so much!  Lesson learned:  Assign to PrivateImplementationType for non-generic type, but use ImplementationTypes.Add() for generic types.

Comment: It's not quite as simple as that. I'd use `ImplementationTypes` for non-generic types too, unless I have to do something different, as seems to be the case here, as I can't otherwise see how to use VB's feature of not having the method name to be the same as the method name in the interface it's implementing.